# Is there a way to run SQL statements on parquet files using dask?

Tags: dask

Spark has a functionality that allows users to run SQL statements on a Spark dataframe. What about Dask? If it is not available now, is it something being considered?

Comment: Pandas has a method query did you try it for dask?

Answer (score 3):

There is also [dask-sql](https://dask-sql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (disclaimer: I am the author), which allows to run arbitrary SQL queries against dask dataframes (or data which can be loaded with dask, e.g. parquet).

For example, after installation with `conda install dask-sql` you are able to run

```py
from dask_sql import Context

c = Context()

c.create_table("my_table", "/some/path/to/parquet")
c.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table").compute()
```

`dask-sql` is very similar to the already mentioned blazingSQL, but also runs without a GPU (cluster).

Answer (score 2):

[BlazingSQL](https://blazingsql.com/) provides a distributed SQL engine in Python that works with Parquet files. It is built on RAPIDS, so it requires NVIDIA GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Presto / AWS Athena may be an answer to your question.